# Jenkins restart error: org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy

Tags: jenkins

For more than one year we have never restarted our jenkins. 
And now after restart we got this error:

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:244)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:47)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1062)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:905)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:227)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/jenkins_home/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:2917)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$700(Jenkins.java:324)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:2935)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:1038)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy : org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy
---- Debugging information ----
message             : org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 8
version             : not available
-------------------------------
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:356)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:270)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:114)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:163)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:282)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.jruby.JRubyMapper.realClass(JRubyMapper.java:34)
    at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:48)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:461)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:327)
    ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the exact same problem today. An exception with: `Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.GithubAuthorizationStrategy`

I found a solution here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34434

The solution was to delete `github-oauth.jpi.disabled` in the plugins folder.

Cheers, Tobias